# Find shape (polygon) with the most overlapping bbox

Tags: sorting, gis, intersection, cql

I'm trying to build a CQL query in order to find a certain shape in my spartial database.

I want my query return the shape with the biggest intersection. My idea was to set LIMIT=1 and sortBy intersection.

If you see the screenshot attached, I would like my query return the following:

**Triangle shapes from left to right**

- Filter1 --> YELLOW SHAPE
- Filter2 --> YELLOW SHAPE
- Filter3 --> GREEN SHAPE

Is there any way to solve my problem?

I'am using the following code so far:

```
    Filter f1 = CQL.toFilter("INTERSECTS(the_geom, POLYGON((10.07051 53.23476, 10.08143 53.23512, 10.07596 53.22838, 10.07051 53.23476)))");
    Filter f2 = CQL.toFilter("INTERSECTS(the_geom, POLYGON((10.06268 53.23756, 10.06889 53.23865, 10.06260 53.24903, 10.06268 53.23756)))");
    Filter f3 = CQL.toFilter("INTERSECTS(the_geom, POLYGON((10.08146 53.24462, 10.09540 53.24761, 10.08247 53.26067, 10.08146 53.24462)))");

    Query query = new Query( typeName, f3);
    query.setMaxFeatures(1);
    source.getFeatures(query);

    SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures(query);
    SimpleFeatureIterator it = features.features();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        SimpleFeature sf = it.next();
        System.out.println(sf.getAttributes());
    }
```

[See the screenshot here](http://s11.postimage.org/4hfc1pjnz/Bildschirmfoto_2012_09_03_um_19_36_09.jpg)

Comment: What is the INTERSECTS code? Cassandra has no spatial extensions.